# Issues with correlation function in R

Tags: r

I am writing a function that takes a directory and a threshold (default of 0) for complete cases as arguments and then performs the cor function for two of the columns. The function runs, kind of. However, whenever I run it it seems like it is skipping everything I have in the function and returns `numeric(0)`. I can't figure out what is causing it to return that. I ran each line through the console and made sure each line worked on its own. But once it comes time to put it all together it seems like it all falls apart. Below is what I'm working with.

```
   corr <- function(directory, threshold =0){
            files <- list.files(path = directory, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = T)
            cr <- numeric()
            
            for(i in seq(files)){
                    data <- read.csv(files[i], )
                    cleandata <- complete.cases
                    data <- data[cleandata, ]
                    if (nrow(data) > threshold){
                            correlation <- cor(data$sulfate,data$nitrate)
                            cr <- append(cr, correlation)
                    }
            }
            return(cr)
    }
```

Edit : removed last part of question. After re-reading I realized that I would not get what I wanted from `return(files)` even if it worked correctly. I should also note that adding the `return(files)` changed my output from `numeric(0)` to `character(0)`

Comment: Inside your loop, your `cleandata` is a copy of the FUNCTION `complete.cases`. I believe you mean to look for complete cases *within your data*, and no function in R is going to guess what data it should operate on. Try `cleandata <- complete.cases(data)`.

Comment: I might add that it might make sense to add an "else" to your `if` conditional that appends an `NA`, at least you would know that it is iterating over the files.

Comment: Shouldn't `cleandata <- complete.cases` be `cleandata <- complete.cases(data)`?  Incidentally, `cr <- append(cr, correlation)` is very inefficient.  Better to get the function to process a single file and then use `lapply` to get the results for all of them.

Comment: Yup, it is most definitely supposed to be `complete.cases(data)`. I also tried added an "else" to append an `NA` but it is still returning the `numeric(0)`. I will also try to mess around with lapply and see if I have any better luck with that.

Comment: Not sure that you need an `if`-clause, fyi: `cor(x,y)` returns `NA` if the lengths are 0 (the "else" clause), `NA` if the lengths are 1, and a number otherwise. I'd think something akin to this might work: `cr <- sapply(files, function(f) { dat <- read.csv(f); with(dat[complete.cases(dat),], cor(sulfate, nitrate)); })`

Comment: @r2evans for the sapply where would my threshold come in to play here? The if loop is where that was supposed to happen but if I am removing that I don't really see another appropriate place for the comparison of complete cases against the threshold.

Comment: It should also be noted that my function is no longer returning `numeric(0)`. It seems to run through the entire function but it comes back as NULL.

Comment: Good point about `threshold`. `sapply(files, function(f) { dat <- read.csv(f); dat <- dat[complete.cases(dat),,drop=FALSE]; if (nrow(dat)>threshold) cor(...) else NA; })` (or such).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this. You put all the files in a dataframe and then map out the correlations. As per @r2evans comment, this adds an `NA` when the threshold condition is not met and as per @Limey comment, this is more efficient than a for loop and append. The benefit here is that we keep the correlation with the file name so that you can see which file has what correlation.

```r
library(tidyverse)


corr <- function(directory, threshold =0){
  tibble(file = list.files(path = directory, 
                           pattern = "*.csv", 
                           full.names = TRUE)) |>
    mutate(data = map(file, read_csv),
           comp = map(data, complete.cases),
           nrw = map_dbl(comp, nrow),
           cr = case_when(
             nrw > threshold ~ map_dbl(comp, ~cor(.x$sulfate, .x$nitrate)),
             TRUE ~ NA_real_
           )) 
}

corr_df <- corr(directory = "user/AndS./stack_questions")
corr_vec <- pull(corr_df, cr)
```